# jquery menu has a white border/background. How to color it?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, background-color

I am currently using the jquery function menu() to create a menu.
Now when I use this, it creates me the menu I want just fine.
But there is one optical thing I want to change:
The Menu (I use it as a button which expands more buttons) has a complete white border that I don't want.
I want it to be black.
Here is what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/H776G/ 
I tried things like `$("#menu a").parent().css('background-color', '000000')`, even with multiple `parent()` calls, but it didn't change anything. 
I just don't know what makes the background white, I don't want it to be white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to remove the padding from all `<ul>` elements. Just add the below code to the .ui-menu CSS.

```
.ui-menu {
    padding: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think about that!
I tried it and exactly that solves the case.
Thank you very much!